# Generally, how do I "go to definition" in VIM? Then how do I with golang?

Tags: vim, go

Two part question:

First, when using VIM what process do I take and what keys do I type to "go to definition" or "go to declaration" etc.? [This document](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Go_to_definition_using_g) might be the answer to my question, but I can't get it to work, so I'm unsure. It looks like its merely text matching the string rather than finding the true definition. If I can get this to work, then will I be able to jump *outside* of the current document to a definition/declaration? Or does this only work within a single document?

Second, how do I make this work specifically with the Go programming language? It sure would be nice to "click" the `Client` in

`clnt := &http.Client{Transport: tr}`

And be taken to the [actual code that defines an http.Client](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/client.go?s=853:1785#L22).

Possible? How?

Comment: there is vim-godef but it doesnt work for me (didnt really spend time to see why)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you guess, `gd` (and other commands) is merely text matching, vim doesn't understand the syntax as it is just a text editor, `:h gd` will explain how `gd` works.

Usually, 'go to definition' is brought by using `CTRL-]` and tag files. A user manual about this topic can be read by `:h 29.1`.

First you need to generate a tags file for your project, as latest *Exuberant Ctags* has supported golang (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204367/ctag-database-for-golang)), command

```
cd /path/to/your/project
ctags -f tags -R --fields=+K+a
```

will do the job.

Second, open vim, by default vim will find tag files under working directory (according to `'tags'` option), if the tag file is found successfully, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>` should works well.

Also check two useful plugins [Tagbar](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar) and [Easytags](https://github.com/xolox/vim-easytags).

Comment: This is only partially working for me... it takes me to random definitions (same symbol name but random file)

Answer (score 4):

For golang, you can use the application godef to do it. The pluging vim-go helps you on setting everything, so, you just type 'gd' in a definition and it goes to the exact definition.

https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/blob/master/doc/vim-go.txt