# How to use ctags for golang?

Tags: go, ctags

I depend heavily upon ctags to traverse between my code.

Can anyone suggest how to use ctags with golang in Mac.

I tried using gotags, but I did not see any tag file generated and I was not able to traverse between the structure definition in vice versa.

Comment: godef (https://github.com/rogpeppe/godef) with emacs and go-mode works very well. Other editors use it as well as far as I know

Comment: If you're looking for an editor, check sublime text + gosublime or visual studio code + go extension, far more superior to using ctags.

Answer (score 5):

[gotags](https://github.com/jstemmer/gotags) work for me: `gotags -R ./* > tags`

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit ~/.ctags for ctags to generate tags with golang.
Check following link [ctag database for Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204367/ctag-database-for-go). Then do the usual `ctags -R`

Answer (score 2):

The usual **ctags -R** works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Universal-ctags (https://ctags.io), an unofficial fork of Exuberant-ctags has built-in Go parser. It is not regex based (== not .ctags based).