# ctags recognise const variable in go

Tags: go, vim, ctags

I use vim+ctags to edit go code. I read the answer of [ctag database for Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204367/ctag-database-for-go) to configure my ctags, but it cann't recognise const variable definition, like this

```
const (
    kMyServiceName     = "serviceName"
    kIpForAnyNetDevice = "0.0.0.0"
)
```

I try `--regex-Go=/const[ \t]+\((\s+([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[ \t]*=\S+)+/\1/v,var/` but it doesn't work.

Does anyone can share your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Universal-ctags captures them.

```
[yamato@master]~% cat /tmp/input.go
cat /tmp/input.go
const (
    kMyServiceName     = "serviceName"
    kIpForAnyNetDevice = "0.0.0.0"
)
[yamato@master]~% ~/var/ctags-github/ctags  --quiet --options=NONE -o - /tmp/input.go
~/var/ctags-github/ctags  --quiet --options=NONE -o - /tmp/input.go
kIpForAnyNetDevice  /tmp/input.go   /^    kIpForAnyNetDevice = "0.0.0.0"$/;"    c
kMyServiceName  /tmp/input.go   /^    kMyServiceName     = "serviceName"$/;"    c
```

Comment: I meet make problem when build universal-ctags: "Makefile:6725: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.". My automake version 1.13.4, autoconf version 2.69, make version 3.82. Do you have any solution? thx

Comment: I have no idea. Please, report it to universal-ctags/ctags project at github.